# Flatten national characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column that contains pet names with national characters. How do I write the query to match them all in one condition?

```
|PetName|

   Ćin
   ćin
   Ĉin
   ĉin
   Ċin
   ċin
   Čin
   čin
```

sth like FLATTEN funciton here:

```
...WHERE LOWER(FLATTEN(PetName)) = 'cin'
```

Tried to cast it to from `NVARCHAR` to  `VARCHAR` but it didn't help. I'd like to avoid using `REPLACE` for every character.

Comment: select lower(cast(N'Časas' as varchar)) works fine for me. What is your database collation set to?

Comment: @Mark PM it does not work for me what you written, I don't know what the collation is, chow can i check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should work because cyrillic collation base cases all diacritics like Đ,Ž,Ć,Č,Š,etc...

```
declare @t table(PetName nvarchar(100))
insert into @t
SELECT N'Ćin' union all 
SELECT N'ćin' union all 
SELECT N'Ĉin' union all 
SELECT N'ĉin' union all 
SELECT N'Ċin' union all 
SELECT N'ċin' union all 
SELECT N'Čin' union all 
SELECT N'čin'

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
WHERE   lower(PetName) = 'cin' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AI
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the collation used for the comparison:

```
WHERE PetName COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI = 'cin'
```

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic
: I borrowed the collation used in your answer. People should vote up Mladen!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way or built-in function that will strip accents from characters.
If you are doing comparisons (LIKE, IN, PATINDEX etc), you can just force COLLATE  if the column/db is not already accent insensitive.

Normally, a query like this

```
with test(col) as (
select 'Ćin' union all
select 'ćin')
select * from test
where col='cin'
```

will return both columns, since the default collation (unless you change it) is insensitive. This won't work for FULLTEXT indexes though.